# Is is possible to create a combo-annotation which combines multiple field annotations?

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I have some boolean fields in my JPA entities which are annotated in the following way:

```
@Column(length = 1)
@Type(type = "yes_no")
private final boolean myField;
```

Is it possible to create a combo-annotation (e. g. MyAnnotation) which combines both of this annotations?

```
@MyAnnotation
private final boolean myField;
```

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you could create an annotation that provides the equivalent of multiple other annotations.

Equally obviously no JPA provider will support it, since they will check for the javax.persistence annotations only (not that @Type is javax.persistence).

Comment: I was and am still not really sure if it is syntactically possibly to create a combo-annotation for field annotations (core of my question), but I guess I don't have to think about it anymore if the JPA provider will not recognize such an annotation, anyway. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is similar to [CDI stereotypes](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/stereotypes.html) - unfortunately, JPA does **not support** such a concept, therefore you must copy recurring annotations all over.

If you can afford to wrap your field into an object, you may mark it as [@Embeddable](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables) and put your field into it - the annotations on that field will be copied wherever you embed that object into an entity. You may extend the annotations using `@AnnotationOverrides`. Obviously, the drawback of such solution is additional complexity when accessing the field in your entity.